# Creating a backbone plugin

Tags: backbone.js, javascript, javascript-framework, marionette

Trying to create a backbone "plugin" that "inherits" from `Backbone.Model` but overrides the `sync` method.

This is what I have so far:

```
Backbone.New_Plugin = {};
Backbone.New_Plugin.Model = Object.create(Backbone.Model);
Backbone.New_Plugin.Model.sync = function(method, model, options){
    alert('Body of sync method');
}
```

The method: `Object.create()` was taken directly from the book ***Javascript: The Good Parts***:

```
Object.create = function(o){
    var F = function(){};
    F.prototype = o;
    return new F();
};
```

I'm getting an error when trying to use the new model:

```
var NewModel = Backbone.New_Plugin.Model.extend({});
// Error occurs inside backbone when this line is executed attempting to create a
//   'Model' instance using the new plugin:
var newModelInstance = new NewModel({_pk: 'primary_key'});
```

The error occurs on line 1392 of the development version of Backbone 0.9.2. inside the function `inherits()`:

```
    Uncaught TypeError: Function.prototype.toString is not generic .
```

I am trying to create a new Plugin in the way that the backbone library `Marionette` creates new versions of Views. IT looks like I am misunderstanding the way that this should be done.

What is a good way to create a new plugin for backbone?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The way you're extending `Backbone.Model` is not how you want to go about it. If you want to create a new type of model, just use `extend`:

```
Backbone.New_Plugin.Model = Backbone.Model.extend({
    sync: function(method, model, options){
        alert('Body of sync method');
    }
});

var newModel = Backbone.New_Plugin.Model.extend({
    // custom properties here
});

var newModelInstance = new newModel({_pk: 'primary_key'});
```

On another note, Crockford's `Object.create` polyfill is considered outdated because (I believe) more recent implementations of `Object.create` take more than one argument. Also, the particular function you're using does not defer to a native `Object.create` function, should it exist, although, you may have just omitted the `if (typeof Object.create !== 'function')` statement that should wrap that function.

Comment: Ah excellent, thanks so much! Yeah, I did omit the Object.create function wrapper because I wanted to reduce the code in the post to a minimum. The version that I work off of does have the wrapper.